# Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005) when assigning values to struct arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Title

```
#define XY 2
#define XPOS 0
#define YPOS 1
#define MAX_X_COORDINATE 64
#define MAX_Y_COORDINATE 64
#define MAX_FRAME 64

typedef struct
{
    int pos[XY];
    char p;//particle
}particle_t;

typedef struct
{
    int index;
    int offset;
    int delay;
    particle_t particle[MAX_X_COORDINATE][MAX_Y_COORDINATE];
}frame_t;

frame_t frame[MAX_FRAME]={0};

int main()
{
    printf("Loading...\n");
    for(int i=0;i<MAX_FRAME;i++)
    {
        frame[i].index=i;
        frame[i].offset=0;
        frame[i].delay=50;
        for(int j=0;i<MAX_X_COORDINATE;j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;i<MAX_Y_COORDINATE;k++)
            {
                frame[i].particle[j][k].pos[XPOS]=j;
                frame[i].particle[j][k].pos[YPOS]=k;
                frame[i].particle[j][k].p=' ';
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

These three lines:

```
frame[i].particle[j][k].pos[XPOS]=j;
frame[i].particle[j][k].pos[YPOS]=k;
frame[i].particle[j][k].p=' ';
```

seemed to cause the problem as removing them made the terminal stop returning `0xC0000005`, but it wouldn't return 0 either. It will just stuck without rerurning anything.

The compiler didn't give any error or warning.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        for(int k=0;i<MAX_Y_COORDINATE;k++)
```

should be

```
        for(int k=0; k<MAX_Y_COORDINATE;k++)
```

That is why always name variable some meaningful and readable name.

Comment: It wasn't there when I posted that :)  Upd: Ok, technically, it was posted a few seconds earlier. It wasn't on my screen when I posted that.

Comment: @ikegami I know, your first comment makes my answer complete.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
for(int j=0;i<MAX_X_COORDINATE;j++)
```

Should be

```
for(int j=0;j<MAX_X_COORDINATE;j++)
```

You have an infinite loop inside an infinite loop.  There is no end condition on the loops because `i` doesn't change.

Edit:  Coincidentally, the return value 0xC00000005 is most like because you are "Overflowing the stack" as it were.